# What is the idiomatic naming convention for local functions in C# 7

Tags: c#, naming-conventions, c#-7.0

Normal class methods, whether instance or static, have an idiomatic naming convention with regards to their casing. It's not clear that there is a convention for [local functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/local-functions), introduced in C# 7.

Should a local function be named in **camelCase**?

```
public static int Factorial(int n)
{
    return calcFactorial(n);

    int calcFactorial(int number) => (number < 2)
        ? 1
        : number * calcFactorial(number - 1);
}
```

Or **PascalCase**?

```
public static int Factorial(int n)
{
    return CalcFactorial(n);

    int CalcFactorial(int number) => (number < 2)
        ? 1
        : number * CalcFactorial(number - 1);
}
```

Comment: I prefer bactrianCamelCase.

Comment: Do not think  there is a "right" answer to this question. 

I would stand to keep naming as it has to be for functions, as it *is a function*, just declared differently. Place of declaration does not alter fundamental properties and semantics of the type and keeping them common across code domain makes things easier to understand, hence to maintain.

Comment: C# convention is that all methods and functions name should be in PascalCase, so I would go with standard convention regardless of their accessibility.

Comment: It's hard to figure what the idiomatic convention is supposed to be. It's not consistent in the documentation and articles found on MSDN.

Comment: I don't get it, for any other type you can have different casing based on the place of declaration, why not for functions?

Comment: I use camelCase for private functions, so I was thinking of using an underscore infront of the name, like _camelCase, because local functions are sort've like "super private," with them being essentially private to the rest of the class.

Comment: Google style guides defer to MS, and then https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/docs/coding-guidelines/coding-style.md, which says: **We use PascalCasing for all method names, including local functions.**

Answer (score 16, accepted):

My standard is always PascalCase, also spell out the full word. I don't like abbreviations as they can have multiple meanings.

So, in your PascalCase scenario, I would spell out the 'Calc' word to be the following:

```
public static int Factorial(int n)
{
    return CalculateFactorial(n);

    int CalculateFactorial(int number) => (number < 2)
        ? 1
        : number * CalculateFactorial(number - 1);
}
```

Compilers have come along ways, and a few extra bytes to make it clear what the method does is worth the few extra keystrokes.

Comment: although it may be recommended but personally I find naming it like this cannot help distinguish it from the ***public*** methods. Especially when you view the source code in some plain text editor (like Notepad). Naming is one way to help distinguish the members. Making the member names look pretty like public will bring the same feeling with the public members which are usually important (kind of public APIs) and should not even be renamed. To me all public members are important, all private members can be freely refactored. I would name it as `calcFactorial` which is still clear enough.

Answer (score 7):

There's no "right" answer to this.

But in our team we're using `_PascalCase()` for local functions.

We already use `_xxx` for private variables, and having an underscore before the function name makes it obvious it's local (like it's "private"). And having PascalCase helps distinguish functions from variables. Also very handy when working with non Visual Studio but basic text editors.

```
public static int Factorial(int n)
{
    return _CalcFactorial(n);

    int _CalcFactorial(int number) => (number < 2)
        ? 1
        : number * _CalcFactorial(number - 1);
}
```

P.S. SO's syntax highlighter does not like this though :)

Comment: The fact that I'm being downvoted just proves, that there's no single truth here. ;) Just make sure your code is consistent, i.e. your team has picked one variant and sticks to it.

Comment: That's true my team also use specific naming convention that adds about 5 letters at the beginning of variables describing its scope/array/type. Its a strange convention but that's what they agreed upon.

Answer (score 5):

There is no right answer, but Microsoft guidelines suggest to use PascalCase:

> When naming public members of types, such as fields, properties, events, methods, and local functions, use pascal casing.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/coding-style/coding-conventions

---

EDIT:
Seems they recently removed that statement. Anyway, they still use PascalCase throughout all the documentation (e.g. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/local-functions), though not explicitly stating that.